# setMobileDataEnabled does not work on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to work with the setMobileDataEnabled method of ConnectivityManager and for some reason i get different results on my emulator and actual device.
On my device (Nexus One, running CyanogenMod 7.0) it works perfectly fine when calling this function and setting the mobile data setting correctly (after getting to this function using reflection):

```
ConnectivityManager connService = (ConnectivityManager) p_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (null != connService)
{
    try
    {
        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);

        if (null != setMobileDataEnabledMethod)
        {
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connService, true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm using the **same** code on the emulator I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.setMobileDataEnabled(ConnectivityManager.java:379)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setMobileDataEnabled(IConnectivityManager.java:540)
```

Nowhere in the documentation (that I could find...) it states that the "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" permission is required for this function and I wonder if this is just an emulator issue or the fact that on my device it works is just some weird coincident ?

Comment: add WRITE_SECURE_SETTING permission on manifest. It will solve

Answer (score 1):

This is a secure setting, you need to be a application with system permissions to set this value. For that you need to sign your application with vendor release keys which i am not sure will be a scalable solution considering you have so many versions of vendor builds of android.

Instead you can try prompting user to launch that screen and set the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I fail to understand how could it WORK on my device and fail on the emulator...

Comment: If possible try on a different device i think you are going to get same error. what is the key with which you have signed your application?

Comment: I signed it with a regular key I created so no system key or something like that