# How to disable mobile data connection in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, connection, 3g

I would like to know if there is any way to disable mobile data connection in android programmatically. Since there is a class known as WifiManager to handle the wifi

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Is there are any such class for handling mobile data connection? How to disable it programmatically in android?

Comment: See code sample on my question on a similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700747/setmobiledataenabled-does-not-work-on-emulator

Answer (score 0):

See [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859551/3103844) and the code is below:

```
public boolean invokeMethod(String methodName, Object[] args) throws Exception {
    ConnectivityManager mcm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class ownerClass = mcm.getClass();
    Class[] argsClass = null;
    if (args != null) {
        argsClass = new Class[1];
        argsClass[0] = args.getClass();
    }
    Method method = ownerClass.getMethod(methodName, argsClass);
    return (Boolean)method.invoke(mcm, args);
}

public Object invokeBooleanArgMethod(String methodName, boolean value) throws Exception {
    ConnectivityManager mcm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class ownerClass = mcm.getClass();
    Class[]  argsClass = new Class[1];
    argsClass[0] = boolean.class;
    Method method = ownerClass.getMethod(methodName,argsClass);
    return method.invoke(mcm, value);
}

/* use these two method like these */
Object[] arg = null;
try {
    boolean isMobileDataEnable = invokeMethod("getMobileDataEnabled", arg);
    if(!isMobileDataEnable){
        invokeBooleanArgMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", true);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```